# Unfortunately, I cannot define or delete a project in my Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Can anyone guide me to create a project in Google Cloud? Because it has a location section, I can't even reset or delete my Google Cloud account. Note that Google account is not my goal. But just delete or reset Google Cloud.

I tested every method you can think of

Comment: Login to https://console.cloud.google.com with your gmail account. If you don't have any project, you should see a button on the home page to create one. If you have existing projects, then select the project drop down list and there should be an icon to create a new project

Comment: Google has documentation on how to close you account: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/close-or-reopen-billing-account  and https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects If you have a problem after following the documentation, edit your question with details.